# I can't download my code on my ST Nucleo F103RB

Tags: c, stm32, keil, nucleo

I bought recently a ST Nucleo F103RB, but I have a problem to download my code on the board.
I'm using Keil µVision for the developement.

Here a screenshot of the configuration for the debug :
Configuration of debug's board on Keil µVision

[image: 1]

But if I download or try to go to the settings of the debug Keil stop working and close.

Can anyone help me to solve my problem. ?

I'm just trying to put my code on the Nucleo board.

Comment: You should ask Keil support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I contact the ARM's support and this is their answer about my problem :

> Which MDK version do you use? I assume that you use version 5.38, which was released almost two weeks ago. If not, please let me know.
> This week we found an issue with the new ST-Link driver, which is included in MDK 5.38. We have seen this with only two customers, and one of my colleagues can duplicate it. We are currently in discussion with ST to find the real reason for this issue.
> Because of this and another (even more important) issue, we have withdrawn MDK version 5.38. Currently, you can download MDK 5.37 from our webserver again. See https://www.keil.com/demo/eval/arm.htm
> With MDK 5.37 this issue should not exist. Please try and let me know.
> We will soon release an MDK version 5.38a. Please don't install this version because it will contain the same ST-Link drivers as the version 5.38.

I was using MDK 5.38 so I've uninstalled MDK 5.38 and Keil µVision, and after reintall Keil µVision and the MDK 5.37. And I can now use the debug ST-Link of the nucleo F103RB.